# How can I prepend an element to every list in a list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have some array

```
 A1 = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}};
```

For each list, I want to add element a0 at the beginning so that my output is

```
 {{a0, a1, b1}, {a0, a2, b2}, {a0, a3, b3}}
```

Without explicitly typing the first entries, how one can implement this? Further, what if I want to instead add some element at the end?

Comment: The available solutions for arbitrary lists of lists are more restricted than solutions for rectangular/tensor arrays.

Comment: Similar [263048](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/263048/iterate-over-without-needing-to-define-a-variable)

Answer (score 10):

```
Prepend[a0] /@ A1
```

{{a0, a1, b1}, {a0, a2, b2}, {a0, a3, b3}}

Also:

```
PadLeft[A1, {Automatic, 3}, a0]
```

Or:

```
A1 /. {a_, b_} :> {a0, a, b}
```

And the new `ReplaceAt`:

```
ReplaceAt[A1, x_ :> Sequence[a0, x], {All, 1}]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
A1 = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}};

Join[{a0}, #] & /@ A1
Catenate[{{a0}, #}] & /@ A1
Replace[A1, {x__} :> {a0, x}, 1]
Transpose@Join[{ConstantArray[a0, Length@A1]}, Transpose@A1]
SequenceCases[A1, {{a_, b__} ..} :> {a0, a, b}]
```

> {{a0, a1, b1}, {a0, a2, b2}, {a0, a3, b3}}

Answer (score 8):

`Join` has also a (rarely used) last integer argument:

```
A1 = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}};

Join[ConstantArray[a0, {3, 1}], A1, 2]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are some ways:

```
{a0, ##} & @@@ A1
Prepend[#, a0] & /@ A1
Insert[#, a0, 1] & /@ A1
ArrayPad[A1, {{0}, {1, 0}}, a0]
```

All yield: {{a0, a1, b1}, {a0, a2, b2}, {a0, a3, b3}}

Answer (score 7):

```
 ArrayFlatten[{{a0,A1}}]

(* {{a0, a1, b1}, {a0, a2, b2}, {a0, a3, b3}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Another one

```
A1 = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}};
lista0 = Table[a0, {i, 1, Length@A1}];
ArrayReshape[Flatten[Transpose[{lista0, A1}]], {Length@A1, Length@A1}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way using `Cases`:

```
Cases[A1, x_List :> Join[{a0}, x]]

(*{{a0, a1, b1}, {a0, a2, b2}, {a0, a3, b3}}*)
```